# Mutating a managed object after it has been removed from its context

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two classes in my core data model: `Sample` and `Photo`, with 1:N relationship.
I use a single `NSManagedObjectContext` in my app which is used as a scratch pad for managed objects. Hence, I always insert a recently created object in the context. If the users chooses to discard her changes, I simply rollback the context. Otherwise, the context is saved.

The error

> CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object 0x1704253a0  (0x1702a1560) after it has been removed from its context.

is printed in the console after after the `Photo` object is deleted from its context. The deletion happens before the context is saved, so the `Photo` `objectID` is temporary. Here is the swift code:

```
function addPhoto(to sample: Sample) -> Photo {
    let photo = Photo(context: managedObjectContext)

    sample.addToPhotos(photo)
    photo.sample = sample

    return photo    
}

function remove(photo: Photo) {
    photo.sample.removeFromPhotos(photo)
    photo.sample = nil

    managedObjectContext.delete(photo)
}

//user adds new Photo
let sample = loadSample() //sample is loaded from database
let photo = addPhoto(to: sample)

//later on user decides to remove the added Photo before the context is saved
remove(photo: photo)
```

The strange thing is that there is no error or exception thrown, and my code completes to the end. However, the error message is printed on the console.

I believe this happens because the context nullifies all `Photo` properties before actually deleting it. I know the properties are nullified because I added observers to them.

How do I prevent this error from showing up in the console?

Thank you.

Comment: If you only use 1 context why aren't you using NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default()? Is your managedObjectContext property being retained properly?

Comment: Ah silly me, you didn't say you were using MagicalRecord. Still worth checking that your managedObjectContext is retain and not overwritten. And could remove(photo) be called on the same object twice?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159502/coredata-error-mutating-a-managed-object-after-it-has-been-removed-from-its-co?rq=1